# HTML5 offline content only works on Chrome.

Tags: html, web2py, offline-caching, cache-manifest

I'm trying to get a website to work in offline mode but it only displays correctly on Chrome. Safari only loads the html (ignores the cache manifest) and firefox doesn't display anything when offline.

By offline, I mean I switch switch off wi-fi and have no internet connection. If using a cache manifest file, shouldn't it still work?

The cache manifest file has the following content:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
/cachetest/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
/cachetest/static/images/logo.png
/cachetest/static/js/main.js
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js
NETWORK:
*
```

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" manifest="cache.manifest">
  <head>
    <title>Offline Content Test</title>
    <link href="/cachetest/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">     
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <img class="span4" src="/cachetest/static/images/logo.png" alt="logo">              
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">        
        <h1>Cache Test</h1>
        <h2>Current Status:<span id="status" class="muted">Wait</span></h2>
        </div>      
    </div>
     </div>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/cachetest/static/js/main.js"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to what I've created: [manifestcache.appspot.com](http://manifestcache.appspot.com/)

I'd like to get it to work on all browsers.

I'm running web2py/Google App Engine in the backend.

Comment: Your manifest file should be named: somename.appcache This might make it work in the other modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. :-(

Comment: Are you sure the manifest file is being served with the MIME type `text/cache-manifest`?

Comment: I just checked with curl, and it is served with `text/cache-manifest`. Strange that cache manifest fetches don't show up in Chromes dev tools network tab…

Comment: @gaige: The MIME type is text/cache-manifest. However, could some of the web2py/GAE added headers be affecting it?